# Connect to Compute Engine From App Engine or CLoud Run with firewall and IAP

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, firewall, identity-aware-proxy

I have an SFTP server running on Google's Compute Engine. The firewall is setup to allow traffic from the Identity aware proxy.

I can connect to the service using `gcloud ssh` locally but I can't connect from App engine or Cloud Run. The service accounts for Cloud Run and App engine already have IAP tunnel and Https permissions.

The backend is written in Node using [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client).

How can I secure the Compute Engine and allow tcp traffic from Cloud Run and App Engine on port 22 to still go through?

Answer (score 0):

**Please look at the UPDATE below.**

There are two possible workarounds:

- **If you use App Engine Standard** you can try [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc):

> **Serverless VPC Access enables you to connect from your App Engine app
> directly to Compute Engine VM instances**, Memorystore instances, Cloud
> SQL instances, and any other resources **with an internal IP address**.

Unfortunately, Serverless VPC Access isn't available for Cloud Run (more in documentation [Services not yet supported](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#unsupported-services)) at the moment, but there's a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138317378) at the Google Public Issue Tracker you can join, comment and track progress. Also, such service isn't available for App Engine Flex as well.

- **If you use App Engine Flex or Cloud Run** follow steps below:

1. [reserve](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) an external static IP
2. [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) `f1-micro` VM instance with reserved external IP address (this likely fits in the Compute Engine [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier))
3. [create](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) a firewall rule to allow connection to SFTP server from reserved external IP
4. create a SOCKS proxy by running a ssh client that routes the traffic through created VM like in this [example](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-static-ip/)
5. [configure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#how-can-i-connect-through-a-socks-proxy) ssh2-sftp-client to use SOCKS Proxy
6. connect to SFTP

**UPDATE:**

No need to use any workarounds. **Serverless VPC Access is now available for Cloud Run**. Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access) for more details.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. It looks like it will work I will accept the answer after trying it.

Comment: Serverless VPC Access is now available for Cloud Run